# Implementação de seletor Select2 com Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, jquery-select2

Sou novo com testes automatizados e Selenium WebDriver (c#), atualmente estou fazendo um teste onde existe um campo de Select2, preciso saber com implementar para o meu teste olhar para este campo e selecionar um valor.

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz com sintaxes seria ótimo.

Comment: Boa tarde, Felipe, sua pergunta está muito vaga, primeiramente dê uma olhada nas nossas diretivas e em seguida reformule a pergunta com mais detalhes
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Obrigado Lucas! Já encontrei uma solução mas já sei como devo fazer para as próximas perguntas, obrigado!